# Epson scanner not found windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

I am unable to connect to my wireless Epson Stylus Photo TX810FW to scan. I am able to print. I am able to view the web panel. The only thing I cannot do is scan. If I open the Epson Scan setting, it searches for the scanner in vain, but answers that it cannot find the scanner. It also stops me from deleting the scanner and adding a new one.

Comment: Have you tried to install the latest drivers and software from Epson?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the latest drivers for Epson Stylus Photo TX810FW from **[hear](http://tech.epson.com.au/downloads/category.asp?sCategory=Multi_Functional&id=StylusPhotoTX810FW&SelOS=Y)**

If it does not help try also this:
 Just delete the printer and add it back.  Sometimes that will work.

I would suggest you take the following actions:

1. Delete your printer using Print & Scan preferfence pane.
2. Delete the folder /Library/Printers/Epson
3. Delete the folder (if present) /Library/Caches/Epson
4. Turn off your printer and then connect it to your computer using a USB connection.
5. Turn the printer on.
6. Go to the Print & Scan preference pane and click the + icon to add your printer.
7. You will be prompted/asked if you want to download the printer drivers for your printer.  Say yes.

Make sure your wifi router dhcp is enabeld and you select the ip auto in printer.

Comment: I have just downloaded and installed the latest drivers and this has not helped I still experience the same problem.